# Unable to load data from multiple level directories into Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hdfs

I created a table the following way

```
CREATE TABLE `default.tmptbl` (id int, name string) ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'escapeChar'='\\','quoteChar'='\"','separatorChar'=',');
```

And I have data in HDFS that have been structured in the following way:

```
/app/tmptbl/
           /DIR1
                /file1.csv
                /file2.csv
           /DIR2
                /file3.csv
                /file4.csv
```

I tried to load the data using the following command:

```
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
LOAD DATA INPATH '/app/tmptbl/' INTO TABLE `default.tmptbl`;
```

However I get the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/app/tmptbl/'': source contains directory: /app/tmptbl/dir1
```

I don't know why even after setting `mapred.input.dir.recursive=true; hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true` didn't make it load data recursively from sub-directories. Am I missing anything?